# Call Twitter API and authentication in Python and Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

How can I authenticate and call twitter api in my project(Python flask and google app engine)

This is my code:

```
twitter = OAuth1Session(TW_CONSUMER_KEY, TW_CONSUMER_SECRET,  
TW_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
TW_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
params = {
            "q" : "xxxxxxxxx",
            "lang": "ja",
            "locale": "ja",
            "since_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
req = self.twitter.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json", 
params = params)
```

I call like that I get these error:

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

But This code is work fine in python(command line)

Comment: Are you using a library to communicate with the Twitter API (for example tweepy, twython)?  If so which one?

Comment: from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session: i'm using these but it's not work what should i use?

Comment: i use with tweepy i have these error(AttributeError: HTTPSConnection instance has no attribute 'sock')

Comment: I had a similar problem (same error message) using the requests_oauthlib. AppEngine wasn't allowing HTTP requests initiated by the requests library. Had to install requests-toolbelt and then "requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()".  See here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests